# ByteArrayOutputStream Out of Memory error when send over socket

Tags: android, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, out-of-memory, bytearrayoutputstream

I am writting a app transfer file based Socket.When I transfer file less than 10 mb ,then no matter what happens.But when I transfer file over 20mb, then I get Out of Memory error and crash my app.

This is my code

```
RandomAccessFile aFile = new RandomAccessFile(path, "r");
FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int n;
while ((n = inChannel.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        buffer.flip();
        total_length += n;
        baos.write(buffer.array(), 0, n);
        byte[] aaa = baos.toByteArray();
        ObjectStream obstream = new ObjectStream("stream", aaa, session_request, total_length);
        aaa=null;
        outt.writeObject(obstream);
        obstream = null;
        baos.reset();
        buffer.clear(); // do something with the data and clear/compact it.
}
inChannel.close();
aFile.close();
```

This is error that geted :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-177
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
at com.jsc.Remote2Droid.Thread.ThreadClientData.run(ThreadClientData.java:705)
```

out of memory at location:

```
byte[] aaa = baos.toByteArray();
```

Please help me fix my code.Thank all.Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for troubles if you place such big files completely in memory before you send them.

So your approach is wrong.

You only need a small buffer. Then make a loop where you read chuncks from the file in the buffer and then write the bytes in that buffer to the output stream.

In this way it't irrelevant how big the file is.

Comment: I only send a small buffer with size is 1024.

Comment: Indeed. Now i see. But why so complicated? Do away with the ByteArrayOutputStream. Do away with the ObjectStream. Make buffer a byte array. Is outt the socket outputstream? Let it derectly write the bytes in buffer.